Valid questions edited by authors to gibberish
I happened to notice this odd behaviour twice recently and I'm wondering why this might be happening. For me this is kind of strange as the questions were legit ones before the edit. Also with valid answers that showed much effort put into them.
Now I can see a closing votes on those as they appear spam but before the edit they would probably never got those votes.
Can something be done to prevent this behaviour? Can Mods revert to the original question & prevent the author the edit again? Should this be done?
2 recent examples:
1) Delutfgjbhbbjggffcbhgvgggf
2) Kjjjhggyffdd errror566544

So far it seems to be a minor issue, so I don't think anything needs to be done right now. If you see such edits in the review queue, just reject them. If thisw keeps up, we'll look at banning the specific offenders and maybe contact the community team for detecting such behavior automatically if it becomes necessary.

Thanks. I'm yet to be able to review the edits (it's from 1k rep so missing 6 pts ;)), but I'm not sure if edits done by author himself are visible in such queue? Aren't those accepted automatically (since it's done but the author)?

you may be right. I’ll ask in the mod chat if anyone has seen such behavior on other sites

@IgorSkochinsky: it is common – alas, I should add – on Stack Overflow. Sometimes it's attempting to "hide" the fact that they asked a dumb or embarrassing question, but the vast majority is done on blatantly obvious homework questions. It is considered extremely toxic behavior, and IIRC, such vandals get a special flag and repeated offenders can expect a ban.

@Igor: In fact I just came across one where the author additionally tried to deface the accepted answer ...
